# How to properly configure Solr to remove duplicate terms in a field

Tags: solr, duplicates

I have build a solr core based off of a mysql product database. The core works fine and I can search for products. The problem I am facing is that when a search term exists in the description multiple times, that product is considered more relevant compared to products that have that term only once in them. Is there a way to tell sonar to not consider duplicates in terms?

I have read about UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory,but have not been able to configure it properly, so I am not even sure if that is a proper way to solve my problem.

I have added this to my solrconfig.xml

```
<processor class="solr.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldRegex">.*_uniq</str>
</processor>
```

I am also not sure how to verify if this config is actually working or not and what impact (if any this has).

Any pointers on how to move forward would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem an indexing one or a relevancy one? Because normally if a term happens several times in a field that document **IS** considered more relevant than others.

If you don't want that, you can redefine the field with [omitTermFreqAndPositions flag](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields) enable, which will not store or take into account how many times term was seen in that specific field.

You will need to reindex all content after this change.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory` filter in the indexing part of you schema.xml to remove duplicates while indexing. Examples of usage are in this [userwiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) and [solrwiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter). This will require re-indexing.

I use the `solr.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory` in my update processor chain to ensure I don't add duplicates during atomic updates. Never tried the behavior of it while document upload. Atomic updates are explained in this [link](http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/) by Yonik. I use it in the following way:

```
<processor class="solr.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldRegex">[NAME OF MY FIELD IN SCHEMA.XML]</str>
</processor>
```

You can test it on a local setup with sample data of the duplicate records.